Is it possible to submit a Docker image as a Spark job to EMR Serverless?
I have a Docker image that contains some application code that interacts with Spark.
Is it possible to submit this image to a Spark cluster for execution?
If so, how?
# Not a real command
$  aws emr-serverless start-job-run --conf image=org/app:latest

This would greatly simplify dependency management, since the container would contain all of the dependencies.
Note: this is a hard thing to research because most search results are about running Spark in Docker Compose.

I did similar thing with dataproc (GCP equivalent of EMR), but you understand these images will be based on extremely restricted hadoop base image, so in most cases, all things considered bootstrap will be better call. Can you elaborate on what's the reasoning behind taking image over bootstrap (what are the dependencies that pushed you that direction)?

Not having to fiddle about with Python virtual envs, native deps and interpreter versions is a big draw.

but emr has these preinstalled i.e. depending on emr version you will get relevant python, spark/scala version etc. why would you use virtual envs on emr in the first place?

There are dependencies that are not supplied by EMR - most things on PyPI

AWS EMR  traditionally doesn’t support running custom Docker containers directly with Spark, but you can achieve a similar result by using AWS EMR on EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service), which allows you to run Spark jobs in Kubernetes
You can find more details here  on how to run EMR on EKS.
